# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. But the header is present

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a problem with a jscropper. I don't know why I receive in console the message

> Failed to load https://cdn.dmove.it/images/409/foto1.jpg: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://www.dmove.it' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I try to read any answer and I understand that is a Cors problem, but by Cors configuration is ok.

```
 curl -H "Origin: https://www.dmove.it" --verbose --head \
    https://cdn.dmove.it/images/412/ionity-cop.jpg >> debugcors.txt

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 13.32.176.105...
* Connected to cdn.dmove.it (13.32.176.105) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 596 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: cdn.dmove.it (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: CN=cdn.dmove.it
*    start date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Sun, 11 Nov 2018 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=Amazon,OU=Server CA 1B,CN=Amazon
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> HEAD /images/412/ionity-cop.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: cdn.dmove.it
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://www.dmove.it
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Length: 113702
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Sat, 04 Nov 2017 10:03:51 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
< Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Nov 2017 21:41:43 GMT
< ETag: "837db6c7a1ae9c54387629ff42fa3684"
< Cache-Control: max-age=315576000
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: AmazonS3
< Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
< Age: 620
< X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 4f95eb10423b781564e79d7c85f85795.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: VDsmZGCzxLz5T9RCPlspCb2zyzjo7US-N5tsb605ojM3fv0jXxafxQ==
<
```

The website is https://www.dmove.it, the distribution is S3 with cloudfront and I whitelist the header in the distribution settings.

What's wrong?

Comment: When I make a request to https://cdn.dmove.it/images/409/foto1.jpg using the fetch API, I get a response with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as expected — though the response is 404.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are hitting a Cloudfront cached response with no CORS headers set. It's also possible your browser is reusing a cached response with no CORS headers set.

Add a Cloudfront "Edge-To-Origin" Origin header to force CORS response headers on every request (xhr or non-xhr):

```
Origin ---> http://sub.domain.com
```